# is it possible to find spearman correlation matrix for multiple variables (around 100) in a single attempt in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I need correlation for around 80 variables that affect the  mode of transportation.

I tried using spearmann correlation but got correlation matrix for only (10X98) . But i need a (98x98) correation matrix.

Any little help would be of great help.

Comment: Provide some code and describe what exactly is wrong, please.

Comment: sex        0.045358294  0.0157643513  0.069422563  0.027247030
lic       -0.007102763 -0.0044325958 -0.015738903  0.018229976
wstat      0.030563195  0.0161875346 -0.019999603  0.053914568
mstat      0.015568622 -0.0009705677  0.043792170 -0.001775963
edustat    0.032293131  0.0892238968  0.070806619 -0.057617208
hcomp      0.019714623  0.0296551498  0.042063418  0.029435980
minc       0.043603164  0.0393559363  0.105062912  0.027361668
job        0.015015833  0.0737375850  0.062723696  0.023678978
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 88 rows ]

Comment: We used this command cor(mtcars, method = "spearman") but please see this "reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 88 rows" we have an issue with that

Comment: I am going to guess wildly that the correlation matrix was calculated, but you are unable to print it in the console, perhaps try `View(cor(mtcars,method="spearman"))` If my guess about the problem is wrong, then this won't help. You really need to edit your question to include all information.

Comment: @  Aaron Hayman - Thaks a ton .. it worked !!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `cor` function from package `stats`, here is an example:

```
cor(mtcars, method = "spearman")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: We used this command cor(mtcars, method = "spearman") but please see this "reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 88 rows" we have an issue with that

Comment: You can change the maximum print with: `options(max.print=10000)` . If that doesn't help, you can select your variables and assign the correlation matrix to an object: `CorrMatrix <- cor(select_if(Your_DF, is.numeric))` , then just round the whole object to fewer decimal places so it doesn't take up so much space and you might be able to see it better: `round(CorrMatrix,2)`